# ProcessBuilder can't access a relative folder location

Tags: java, cmd, processbuilder

I'm trying to execute a third party JAR from Java code using `ProcessBuilder`. This JAR requires that you must be at the installation directory when executing this JAR, otherwise it will not work. Below is the folder structure for this third party JAR:

```
C:\\Program Files\\MSG MCE Software I10
C:\\Program Files\\MSG MCE Software I10\\jre
C:\\Program Files\\MSG MCE Software I10\\jre\\bin
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
String cmdLine = "\"jre\\bin\\java\" -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp \"C:\\Program Files\\MSG MCE Software I10\\msgmce.jar;C:\\Program Files\\MSG MCE Software I10\\*:.\" com.mmm.his.msgmce.Main -i \"C:\\drginput\\"+inFileName+"\" -o \"C:\\drgoutput\\"+outFileName+"\" ";
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder( "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"C:\\Program Files\\MSG MCE Software I10\"&&"+cmdLine);
System.out.println("cmdLine->"+cmdLine); 
Process p = builder.start();
```

As you can see I initially try to navigate to the installation directory `"C:\\Program Files\\MSG MCE Software I10\"` and then try to execute the java executable file.

Problem is that I'm getting a `"System cannot find file specified"` because it can't find the relative path of `"jre/bin/java"`.

Now this works on one machine but not on another machine.  When creating the `ProcessBuilder` and invoking the `cmd.exe`, I'm navigating to the installation home directory, so I should be able to access the `jre/bin/java` file.

Does anyone have any idea why this would work on one machine but not another one?

Comment: Are you sure that `C:\Program Files\MSG MCE Software I10\ `  exists?

Comment: Yes it exists.  Just realized that Eclipse and JAR were on different drives. It seems that doing change directory from ProcessBuilder from D to C was not working.  Maybe a Java limitation for security reasons? Not sure.

Answer (score 2):

OK I figured this out.  On the computer where it was working, all programs like Eclipse, Tomcat were installed on the same C drive, but on the other computer Eclipse was installed on a different drive.

The third party JAR was installed on C drive and my program was running on Eclipse but on the D drive.  For some reason the change directory in ProcessBuilder to the C drive was not working. Not sure if this is a limitation of ProcessBuilder for security reasons, but installing everything on a single drive worked.

Comment: FYI: You can't change drives by using `cd`. To change drives from `D:\ ` to `C:\ ` you have use `C:` before executing the `cd` command. Your command could resemble the following: `"C:&cd \"C:\\Program Files\\MSG MCE Software I10\"&&"+cmdLine`